# iPhone's Emergency Alerts do not make a sound when on silent mode even with "Always deliver" option on

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, alert

I just received today's scheduled test Emergency Alert (Aug 11, 2021 11:20 PDT).

My phone was on silent mode, right in front of me. I noticed the alert about 2 minutes later because the alert didn't make any sound. My phone was with the phone's side switch on silent. I checked the settings in Settings > Notifications > Emergency Alerts, and the "Always deliver" option was ON, so the alert should have made a sound.

I have some apps with notifications set to bypass the silent mode and they do work.

The phone is an iPhone Xs (MT9C2LL/A) with OS version 14.6. My service provider is T-Mobile but I bought my phone from Apple unblocked.

Any ideas why I'm not getting the emergency alerts to make a sound while the phone is on silent mode?

Comment: We don't have this feature in the UK so I've no way to test - but I just saw this in the news this morning, might be helpful. Apparently real & test alerts have different settings - https://9to5mac.com/2021/08/11/turn-on-off-emergency-test-alerts-iphone/